# Need "diversity" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was recently advised by a friendly moderator that when I want to create a tag, I should not just go ahead and create it.  Rather, I should bring it up at Meta.

However, there was a question about a "diversity" tag already, and there someone said, Just create it on the fly when the need arises.  Which is what I did, since I think this one is a slam dunk.  More and more universities are working hard to recruit if not diverse faculty members, at least culturally competent candidates.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a useful tag. It isn't already covered well by any existing tags (there is just a little bit of overlap with [gender](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender)), and it can be applied to some existing questions on this site.  For example:

- [Role of positions' geographical diversity in (US) academic career perspectives](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/role-of-positions-geographical-diversity-in-us-academic-career-perspectives?s=4|2.2946)
- [What do admission committees look for in a diversity essay?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32484/what-do-admission-committees-look-for-in-a-diversity-essay?s=5|2.2495)
- [How to foster gender diversity as an organizer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34923/how-to-foster-gender-diversity-as-an-organizer?s=6|2.1913)
- [What should go in a diversity statement if I believe I have had no relevant experiences?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32735/what-should-go-in-a-diversity-statement-if-i-believe-i-have-had-no-relevant-expe?s=7|1.9764)
- [Why are some research groups not so ethnically diverse?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/why-are-some-research-groups-not-so-ethnically-diverse)

I have created the following tag wiki excerpt for this tag, to clarify when it should be applied:

> On the diversity of academic disciplines, institutions, or events, including ethnic, gender, socioeconomic, geographical, or other kinds of diversity. Includes questions about diversity statements, increasing diversity of participants in an event, lack of diversity, and others.

Comment: Could you add something about disability, please?

Comment: @aparente001 You can edit a tag wiki excerpt (or rather, suggest an edit), just like you can edit any other content on this site. Click on the tag and then click on "improve tag info."

Comment: The tag excerpt seems very obscure to me. "diversity of academic disciplines" to me means "people working on different topics", which is probably not what you mean here. Also, you do not really give a definition of *diversity*, but you just keep repeating that word many times (five times in three rows).

Comment: I have suggested a new excerpt for [tag:diversity]; it is currently in the peer review queue. I hope it is accurate, since diversity is mostly an US concept, and I am not an expert in these issues myself. Feel free to suggest other changes or improvements.